# Programmatically created UITableViewCell subclass only working on highlight

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've created a subclass of UITableViewCell but I'm struggling to get it to work properly. If I use `UITableViewStyleDefault` then the class only works when highlighted. If I use `UITableViewStyleValue1` then it mostly works but I'm unable to change label fonts much.

I tried researching but it seems everyone is doing this via a .xib file, but not programmatically.

Implementation file
    #import "ASCustomCellWithCount.h"

```
@implementation ASCustomCellWithCount
@synthesize primaryLabel,secondaryLabel,contentCountImage,contentCount;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    contentCountImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"tableCount.png"] ];
    primaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    primaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    primaryLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    primaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 20];
    primaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    secondaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    secondaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    secondaryLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    secondaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 8];
    secondaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    contentCount = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    contentCount.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    contentCount.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 15];
    contentCount.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    contentCount.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    contentCount.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    contentCount.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.contentView addSubview: contentCountImage];
    [self.contentView addSubview: primaryLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview: secondaryLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview: contentCount];
}
return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];
CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
//    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;
primaryLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,0, 200, 25);
secondaryLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 100, 15);
contentCount.frame = CGRectMake(contentRect.size.width - 48, contentRect.size.height / 2 - 13, 36, 24);
contentCountImage.frame = CGRectMake(contentRect.size.width - 48, contentRect.size.height / 2 - 12, 36, 24);
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)dealloc {
[primaryLabel release];
[secondaryLabel release];
[contentCountImage release];
[contentCount release];
}
@end
```

And then to create the cell I use

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

ASCustomCellWithCount *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[ASCustomCellWithCount alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tempArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];
cell.contentCount.text = @"49";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the `textLabel` text rather than the `primaryLabel` and `secondaryLabel` labels' text? Also, the `contentCount` label is white and presumably the background is white so that might be why it's only showing on highlight?

Comment: No idea why I hadn't changed textLabel, thanks for spotting that. As for the contentCount, underneath there is a image view (contentCountImage) which is dark grey, so the label should still show up.

Comment: OK I don't know why, but simply changing the `textLabel` to `primaryLabel` has made the custom style work. Thanks. All I needed was a fresh pair of eyes :)

Comment: `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` are already subviews of `UITableViewCell` when using `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. Since you are adding your own labels, you have to set the text for those since they cover the default labels. 
For the `contentCount` label, try to hard code its frame instead of using `self.contentView.bounds` just to see if you may be getting an unexpected value for its `CGRect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, my issue was trying to use the custom cells default `cell.textLabel.text` rather than my custom `cell.primaryLabel.text`.

As soon as you use one of the default objects in a cell it reverts to the default cells rather than a subclass.